# Connection refused trying to read from RabbitMQ Queue on Cloud Foundry using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, spring-amqp

I am trying to use RabbitMQ for posting messages from one application and receiving them in another. These applications are hosted on Cloud Foundry and both have been bound to the same instance of RabbitMQ.

I am able to post messages to the queue from the first application, but in my second application, which uses @RabbitListener and @RabbitHandler to listen to this queue, I am getting a Connection Refused error. It works well on my local instance of RabbitMQ though.

> Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection
>   factory supports it. Exception summary:
>   org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: errno: 111 (Connection refused), error:
>   Connection refused (local port 45596 to address 127.0.0.1 (localhost),
>   remote port 5672 to address 127.0.0.1 (localhost))

This is the complete log.

The remote port, I observe, remains the same at 5672, but the local port keeps changing from log to log. I am not sure where these ports are picked up from, as I assume Spring should be handling this for me, and also because I have a similar setup for my first application, which seems to be working fine.

Here is how my config looks-

```
@Bean
        public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
            return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        }

        @Bean
        public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
        }

        @Bean
        public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
            rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
            return rabbitTemplate;
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
            container.setQueueNames("queue2911");
            container.setAutoStartup(false);
            //container.setMessageListener(exampleListener());
            return container;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operating system picks the local port.

The fact that you are attempting to connect to `localhost` implies you are using a connection factory with defaults (localhost:5672) instead of the boot configured one.

Turn on DEBUG logging for both apps and compare the auto configuration reports.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue with my first app earlier when I was creating beans for the connection factory there myself. In order to resolve that, I switched to passing the connection factory as a parameter to the rabbit template constructor instead, and that worked. I followed a similar approach here then, but here, I am not able to understand how these configs map to my @ rabbitlistener, as unlike my first app, there is no autowiring, but just annotations. Could you help me figure how these beans here actually map to the @ rabbitlistener and @ rabbithandler annotations please? Thanks!

Comment: Spring Boot auto configuration creates a connection factory bean and a rabbit listener container factory bean, which is used to create the listener container for each `@RabbitListener` annotation - see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java#L62).

Comment: Aah. I see. So essentially @RabbitListener should not require any extra config apart from the enable rabbit?

Comment: Correct, unless you need to perform additional custom configuration beyond what is available using boot properties.

Comment: Great. Thanks, Gary! I shall try that.

Comment: I tried this approach, removing all rabbit config and only using @RabbitListener, but I still face a similar message.

Comment: Sorry, you were right Gary. Actually, I had another config for my db in the receiver app, which was extending AbstractCloudConfig. I was able to get the scenario working by either extending AbstractCloudConfig for both my db and rabbit configs or removing both configs altogether. 
I guess then Spring was not creating a proper connection factory bean for my rabbit config earlier because it could see this factory bean already in AbstractCloudConfig?

Comment: That is correct; in general boot only auto-configures beans if the user has not already configured beans of the same type and/or bean name - see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/amqp/RabbitAutoConfiguration.java#L86) for example.

Comment: @NisheethAgarwal I have simliar problem with mongodb. What did you have to remove in your configuration to make this work?

Comment: For me, it worked with only the RabbitListener annotation. Letting Spring take care of all bean creations. When I had to extend AbstractCloudConfig though, I made sure I was using it for all my configs. Initially, it wasn't working for me because I was extending AbstractCloudConfig for my db config, but not for my Rabbit config. Maybe you have a similar issue with your ConnectionFactory?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by including

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.pivotal.cfenv</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-cfenv-boot</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in my `pom.xml`.  I am using Spring Boot 2.7.2 with `spring-boot-starter-amqp`.